# How to convert const char* root_0_Title = "0x21,0x32,'I',0x0f,0x00" to uint8_t data[5]={0x21, 0x32, 0x49, 0x0f, 0x00};

Tags: casting, arduino-c++

I have the below code reading data from the API.

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

const char* ssid = "****";
const char* pass = "****";

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  //  Serial.print("COnnecting");

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    //    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }

  //  Serial.print("\nIP Address");
  //  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

int dataReceived = 0, dataSent = 0;

void loop() {
  const char* root_0_id ;
  const char* root_0_Title ;
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED && dataReceived == 0)
  {
    long rnd = random(1, 3);
    HTTPClient client;

    client.begin("https://6336d6c365d1e8ef267481aa.mockapi.io/user?id=1");
    int httpCode = client.GET();

    if (httpCode > 0) {
      String payload = client.getString();
      //      Serial.println("\nstatuscode: " + String(httpCode));
      if (payload == "[]")
        //Serial.println("\nNOT FOUND");
        ;
      else
      {
        //Serial.println(payload);

        DynamicJsonDocument doc(49152);

        DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, payload);

        if (error) {
          //          Serial.print("deserializeJson() failed: ");
          //          Serial.println(error.c_str());
          return;
        }

        root_0_id = doc[0]["id"]; // "41"
        root_0_Title = doc[0]["Bitmap"];

        //        Serial.print("\n\nData : ");
        //        Serial.println(root_0_Title);

        //        Serial.println(sizeof(root_0_Title));
        client.end();
        dataReceived = 1;
        delay(2000);
      }

    }
    else {
      Serial.println("Error on HTTP request");
    }
  }
  if (dataReceived == 1 && dataSent == 0)
  {
    Serial.write(root_0_Title, 40997);
    dataSent = 1;
  }
  //delay(1000);
}
```

While I'm sending `root_0_Title`, it is getting sent as a string that's why I had to use the size of it as 40997 in `Serial.write(root_0_Title, 40997);`, while the actual data is 8199 (which is separated by commas ',').

So is there a way to convert the const `char* root_0_Title = "0x21, 0x32, 'I', 'F', 0x00"` to `uint8_t data[5]={33, 50, 73, 16, 0};`?

I have gone through several questions I found :

```
const char* hexstring = "0x0f, 0x41";
unsigned int number = (int)strtol(hexstring, NULL, 16);
```

But this only converts the first data i.e. `number = 16`, but not the array of data.
Anyone can guide me, please?

Comment: I think you can split the array by ',' firstly, then convert the data to uint if you can prove the data format is right

Comment: I posted an answer below on how to convert the ascii string containing numeric hex literals and quoted char literals  into a byte array.  But passed on the URL output I suddenly realized you are really parsing JSON - and you're trying to do it manually (the hard way). I'd highly recommend you parse the response from the server using any available open source json parsing code for C/C++. There's plenty out there.  Then use the suggestion I posted below on how to covert the specified string field ("Bitmap") into a byte array.

Comment: almost the same question on Arduino SE with answer without using standard library https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/90981/conversion-from-const-char-datac-0x21-0x10-0xfa-0x7a-0xff-to-uint8-t-data

Answer (score 0):

> How to convert const char* root_0_Title = "0x21,0x32,'I',0x0f,0x00" to uint8_t data[5]={0x21, 0x32, 0x49, 0x0f, 0x00};

Like this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<uint8_t> convert(const std::string& s)
{
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    std::vector<uint8_t> result;

    while (std::getline(ss, item, ',')) 
    {
        uint8_t value = 0;

        // get rid of any leading whitespace
        while (item.length() > 0 && std::isspace(item[0]))
        {
            item = item.substr(1);
        }

        if ((item.length() > 1) && (item[0] == '\''))  // char literal
        {
            value = (unsigned char)(item[1]);
        }
        else // parse as number
        {
            value = std::strtoul(item.c_str(), nullptr, 16);
        }

        result.push_back(value);

    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    const char *s = "0x21,0x32,'I',0x0f,0x00";
    uint8_t data[5] = {};
    auto vec = convert(s);
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), data);

    // validate the bytes in data
    bool success = true;
    uint8_t expected[5] = {0x21, 0x32, 0x49, 0x0f, 0x00};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
       if (expected[i] != data[i])
       {
          success = false;
       }        
    }
    std::cout << (success ? "pass" : "fail") << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```